# Residues more than one singularity at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Having trouble calculating the residue at 0 for this integral within the unit circle
I understand that its a pole of order 3 because both the z^2 and the sinz have singularities at 0. Is there an easier way to find this residue without resorting to finding the laurent series around z of $\frac{cscz}{z^2}$?

$\int \frac{1}{z^2sinz}~dz$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the following formula :

If $f(z)$ has pole of order $n$ at $c$ then residue at $c$ is given by

$$\mathrm{Res}(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( (z-c)^{n}f(z) \right)$$

Comment: Yes but then would you not just be taking the second order derivative of 1?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your idea... why would you take second order derivative of $1$?

Comment: Oh I see so it would be the second derivative of z^3/z^2sinz which is just the second derivative of z/sinz...

Comment: exactly!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but I don't have 15 reputation yet!

Comment: That is alright... I would be happy if you can actually work it out and let me know the answer